# Must speed up row-wise operations

Tags: r

I need to do row-wise operations more than 15 million times, but have too slow code. Here is a small reproducible example:

```
costMatrix1 <- rbind(c(4.2,3.6,2.1,2.3),c(9.6,5.5,7.2,4.9),c(2.6,8.2,6.4,8.3),c(4.8,3.3,6.8,5.7))
costMatrix2 <- costMatrix1 #Example, the costMatrix2 is actually different from costMatrix1

tbl_Filter <- rbind(c(0,0,0,4),c(1,2,3,4),c(1,0,3,0),c(1,2,0,0),c(1,2,0,4))

tbl_Sums <- data.frame(matrix(0, nrow=10, ncol=2))
colnames(tbl_Sums) <- c("Sum1","Sum2")

for (i in 1:nrow(tbl_Filter))
{
  tbl_Sums[i,1] <- sum(costMatrix1[tbl_Filter[i,],tbl_Filter[i,]])
  tbl_Sums[i,2] <- sum(costMatrix2[tbl_Filter[i,],tbl_Filter[i,]])
}
```

I think to replace the for-loop with ddply is the solution, but I can't get it to work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you have very large arrays to work with, you are probably better off sticking to base R.

Here is how you could use `sapply` to solve the summing problem for a single matrix.  Then use it repeatedly on each input matrix:

```
sumOne <- function(cost, filter){
  sapply(1:nrow(filter), function(i)sum(cost[filter[i,], filter[i,]]))
}


cbind(
    sumOne(costMatrix1, tbl_Filter),
    sumOne(costMatrix2, tbl_Filter)
)
```

The results:

```
     [,1]  [,2]
[1,]  5.7  11.4
[2,] 85.5 171.0
[3,] 15.3  30.6
[4,] 22.9  45.8
[5,] 43.9  87.8
```

This should be much, much faster than your loop.  Not because of the fact that a `for` loop is intrinsically slower than sapply (it's not), but because `sapply` automatically reserves memory for the result, combined with the fact that `[<-` is slow.

Comment: This: `t(apply(tbl_Filter,1,function(x){c(sum(costMatrix1[x,x]),sum(costMatrix2[x,x]))}))` will be very slightly faster, I think. A tad more if the OP is willing to omit the transpose.

Answer (score 4):

If you have more than one CPU core, using `snowfall` might help you speed this up.  The setup (pre-parallelization):

```
newfun = function(n) {
  a <- sum(costMatrix1[tbl_Filter[n,],tbl_Filter[n,]])
  b <- sum(costMatrix2[tbl_Filter[n,],tbl_Filter[n,]])
  c(a,b)
  }

nvec = matrix(data = 1:nrow(tbl_Filter), ncol = 1)

t = proc.time()
out = t(apply(nvec,1,function(x) newfun(x)))
proc.time() - t
```

Now, parallelized:

```
## load 'snowfall' package
require(snowfall)

## Initialize parallel operation --> choose number of CPUs here!
sfInit( parallel=TRUE, cpus=2 )

##################################################################
## 'Export' functions and variables to all "slaves" so that parallel calculations
## can occur

sfExport(list=list('newfun'))

sfExport('costMatrix1')
sfExport('costMatrix2')
sfExport('tbl_Filter')
sfExport('nvec')

## call function using sfApply; will return values as a list object
 out = sfApply(nvec, 1, function(x) newfun(x))

## stop parallel computing job
sfStop()

tbl_Sums = as.data.frame(t(out))
colnames(tbl_Sums) <- c("Sum1","Sum2")
```

Answer (score 2):

Not sure how the speed would compare, but you could also set up matrices to do matrix multiplication.  This uses the fact that the information in your `tbl_Filter` has positive numbers in the columns you want to sum.

```
> ttt <- apply((tbl_Filter>0)*1,1,function(x) x %*% t(x))
> t(rbind(as.numeric(costMatrix1), as.numeric(costMatrix2)) %*% ttt)
     [,1]  [,2]
[1,]  5.7  11.4
[2,] 85.5 171.0
[3,] 15.3  30.6
[4,] 22.9  45.8
[5,] 43.9  87.8
```

Comment: @Andrie, Thanks, I thought so too but I suspect it will depend on what's big, the filter or the matrix; it's not clear how much faster the `apply` here might (or might not) be than the `sapply` in your solution.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the `snowfall` library mentioned above, there's also `multicore` that only implements the parallel version of `lapply` (called `mclapply`) and not of `apply`, but it's easy to rewrite the code to accommodate this:

```
newfun = function(n) {
  a <- sum(costMatrix1[tbl_Filter[n,],tbl_Filter[n,]])
  b <- sum(costMatrix2[tbl_Filter[n,],tbl_Filter[n,]])
  c(a,b)
}

nvec = matrix(data = 1:nrow(tbl_Filter), ncol = 1)

# single-core version using apply
out = t(apply(nvec,1,newfun))

# multicore version using mclapply
library(multicore)
out.list = mclapply(1:nrow(nvec),function(i)newfun(nvec[i,]))) 
out = do.call("rbind", out.list) 

# if the number of rows is huge, this will be much faster than do.call:
library(data.table)
out = rbindlist(out.list)
```